# Google Analytics is not working on Streamlit Application

Tags: python, google-analytics, streamlit

I have built a web application using streamlit and hosted it on the Google Cloud Platform (App Engine). The URL is something like `https://xxx-11111.uc.r.appspot.com/` which is given for the Stream URL.

I enabled Google Analytics 2 days back but apparently, it is not set up correctly.

It was given that I need to add in the head tag.

This is the code where I added the Google Analytics tag...

What is wrong??

```
def page_header():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="xx", page_icon="images/logo.png")
    header = st.container()
    with header:
        # Add banner image
        logo = Image.open("images/logo.png")
        st.image(logo, width=300)

        # Add Google Analytics code to the header
        ga_code = """
        <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxxx"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxx');
        </script>
        """
        st.markdown(ga_code, unsafe_allow_html=True)


# Define the main function to run the app
def main():

    # Render the page header
    page_header()

    .....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to implement Google Analytics into your GAE Streamlit app would be to add the GA global site tag JS code to the default /site-packages/streamlit/static/index.html file

NOTE: This script should be run prior to running the streamlit server

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil
import pathlib
import logging
import streamlit as st


def add_analytics_tag():
    # replace G-XXXXXXXXXX to your web app's ID
    
    analytics_js = """
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
    </script>
    <div id="G-XXXXXXXXXX"></div>
    """
    analytics_id = "G-XXXXXXXXXX"

    
    # Identify html path of streamlit
    index_path = pathlib.Path(st.__file__).parent / "static" / "index.html"
    logging.info(f'editing {index_path}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(index_path.read_text(), features="html.parser")
    if not soup.find(id=analytics_id): # if id not found within html file
        bck_index = index_path.with_suffix('.bck')
        if bck_index.exists():
            shutil.copy(bck_index, index_path)  # backup recovery
        else:
            shutil.copy(index_path, bck_index)  # save backup
        html = str(soup)
        new_html = html.replace('<head>', '<head>\n' + analytics_js) 
        index_path.write_text(new_html) # insert analytics tag at top of head
```

Comment: I tried this. and there's a pop of 'Streamlit runs JavaScript'. I then replaced the string with google tag string, but google analytics still says that 'Data collection isn’t active for your website.' There are 2 problems I think are possible: 
1. google analytics code must be the 1st thing in header, but also set_page_config(), I have put set_page_config() before because it gives error otherwise.
2. my website URL is the free one from google cloud platform, which is like https://xxxx-11111.uc.r.appspot.com/

Comment: please see updated answer - this is how I've successfully implemented a GA tag on my deployed streamlit app with app engine. note that this script should be run prior to running the streamlit server

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is working now! I had added your given code before but in my main application file. Your note - 'this script should be run prior to running the streamlit server' is what fixed my issue. I moved that code to another python file and edited my dockerfile